# Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(max, [AbsoluteLocationPath

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an issue while i am trying to execute the `XSLT` program.Need your help to know why this exception issue is occurring.

> Transformer Configuration Exception occurred when loading XSLT CreateTicket_new.xsl; details: Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(max, [AbsoluteLocationPath(ParentLocationPath(ParentLocationPath(ParentLocationPath(ParentLocationPath(ParentLocationPath(step("child", 19), step("child", 1, pred(!=(funcall(name, []), literal-expr(header))))), step("child", 41)), step("child", 37)), step("child", 42)), step("child", 3)))])'. See error logs for details

I am using XSLT 2.0 Version.

I am using from SAP PO tool.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code? Are you sure you are using XSLT 2.0 with an XSLT 2 processor? Which tool/processor gives that error message for which line of code?

Comment: hello Martin  I am unable to post the xslt as the system is not allowing me to post more than 30k length data.

Comment: Do you have any more details on the error? The message says "See error logs for details", do the logs give any indication about the line number in the XSLT where the error occurs?

Comment: I think the error message looks like the one the Xalan Java XSLT 1.0 processor gives when being fed XSLT 2 code with functions like `max` that it doesn't support so you will need to find out/make sure that you have your tool use Saxon 9. It might help to add a tag for the tool you use, I don't think many people reading questions with the tag [tag:xslt-2.0] will be able to help with "SAP PO".